# How to get network path from local path?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a local path like `C:\Users\some_user\Desktop\some_folder\attachments\20150210115`. I need to generate network path with python like `\\PC_NAME\C:\Users\some_user\Desktop\some_folder\attachments\20150210115` or something like this to get this folder from other windows pc. Is it possible to do in python automatically or I need just to hardcode local path replacing pc name and other staff?

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I not so familiar with Windows path as I live in Linux. I just need to generate network path for local path and send it to other device.

Comment: do you mean `socket.gethostname()`?

Comment: What have you tried so far, ie. what were your internet searches? If it's possible, it's probably done with some win32 library, and I'm not knowledgeable about these.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your existing path is store in a variable called `localPath` you can do:

```
  import socket
  PCname=socket.gethostname()
  networkPath='\\'+PCname+'\\'+localPath
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this?

```
import socket

computer_name = socket.gethostname()
path = r"C:\Users\some_user\Desktop\some_folder\attachments\20150210115"

network_path = "\\" + computer_name + "\\" + path
```

Answer (score 0):

Having thought about the problem itself: No, it's not possible to do this in any general way, because there's absolutely no reason why `C:\path\to\file` should correspond to `\\PCNAME\C:\path\to\file`; that requires that the folder `C:\` has the share name `C:`, which might be canonical on windows machines, but not fixed. In fact, normal users don't even get to read the full list of shares of a windows computer including their local bindings.

EDIT: as the others pointed out, there are ways to get your machines network name, but you'll have to build the network path with that manually, and I think your question was about automatically matching a file to it's windows share "URL".